# PHP placeholders regex

Tags: php, regex, string

my regular expression returns wrong strings

```
preg_replace_all("/\{\{([^W]+)\}\}/", $this->outputHtml,$matches);
```

I'm trying to match placeholders within template that have `{{this}}` syntax.
What I'm getting matched is first occurence of `{{` and last `}}` with all text in between including a lot of html.

Comment: Do you really want to match any double curly braces that don't have a capital W between them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lazy repetition answers work great, but I personal avoid it when possible (since we can be more *"specific"* with what we want to match).  I would use [this expression](http://regex101.com/r/zY2dC1):

```
\{{2}      (?# match 2 literal {)
(          (?# start capture group)
 [^}]+     (?# 1+ non } characters)
)          (?# end capture group)
\}{2}      (?# match 2 literal })
```

This captures 1+ ***non***-`}` characters, meaning it will stop as soon as it sees the closing `}}`.  However, this means a `{{foo}bar}}` template would not work (however, I don't think that would be a problem).

**Implementation:**

```
preg_replace_all("/\{{2}([^}]+)\}{2}/", $this->outputHtml, $matches);
```

Comment: Side note: not saying this is better or worse than the lazy examples before mine; just wanted to give another look.

Comment: Probably is better since it avoids any backtracking that the lazy answers suffer from

Comment: +1, you're right that's more efficient than lazy which causes backtracking. Reading a few of your regex answers, nice work. :)

Comment: Thanks @zx81, I've learned the bulk of my regular expression knowledge by mulling around SO answering questions.

Answer (score 4):

Make it ungreedy then:

```
preg_replace_all("/\{\{([^\W]+)\}\}/U", $this->outputHtml,$matches);
```

The `U` modifier is a PHP extension not originally present in Perl. Reference: [Pattern Modifiers](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php).

**Edit** — For the big picture (variable replacing in templates), I normally go the other way round: since I know the place-holder names in advance, I simply look for the literal tags and get them replaced with `e.g.` [good old `strtr()`](https://www.php.net/strtr). E.g.:

```
// Totally untested code
$from = $to = array();
foreach($values as $key => $value){
    $from[] = "{{$key}}";
    $to[] = $value;
}
... = strtr($this->outputHtml, $from, $to);
```

Comment: @AD7six - Well spot :)

Comment: Is there a reason you use the `U` modifier?  I would prefer to have the `?` so someone reading the regular expression would notice greedy vs. lazy right away, without having to familiarize themselves to PHP's modifiers.

Comment: @Sam - A reason? When greediness matters, I normally want it for the whole expression. When used more than once, this syntax is shorter and the flag stands out. When coding in PHP I assume PHP knowledge. — Other than that, it's a matter of personal preference and there's already another answer with the Perl syntax. I've also edited my answer to explain how I solve templating needs myself.

Comment: Fair enough :) -- I added a plus one for the elaborated explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `?` along with `+` to make it ungreedy (aka 'lazy'):

```
preg_replace_all("/\{\{([^W]+?)\}\}/", $this->outputHtml,$matches);
```